# How to create Trailer Record in Flat File using SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

I am looking for some help on how to create a trailer record in a flat file using SSIS, I have create a SSIS package that creates a custom header and loads other record from the database into the flat file, it is a fixed width flat file. Now at the end of the file I want to create a Trailer Record along with some static text and Record count. I tried looking on to google but could not get any good example. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't totally clear what you want to do, perhaps give some example data and show what you have tried.  If you are simply trying to populate some destination with source data and want an appended record create a second source and UNION ALL to append the record.  The second source will be where you create the trailer record.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Script Task. Take the file path of the fixed width flat file that you have obtained as a input variable. Once withing the script task use the .Net coding to append the data that you need. I have written a post on it - https://karbimantras.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/adding-record-count-to-flat-file/